# What is the maximum file size of plugin/workflow library in CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

Could you advise the maximum file size of plugin/workflow library in CRM?

I am using ILMerge to merge OpenXML library with my workflow library so that I can try creating a spreadsheet in an CodeActivity. But it failed when deploying the merged library to server. I think because the library size is too big (10.6 MB).

Comment: http://www.ryanjones.io/2011/05/28/uploading-large-crm-2011-plugins/

Comment: @Donal Thanks. I am using CRM 2013 Online. I think I will try another library.

Comment: oh, ok. Have you though about creating a CSV file instead? It would open in Excel as a spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes, I have. But the spreadsheet have custom format like a time table with activities expand through multiple columns and rows. A CSV is not sufficent.

Comment: You have the file size limitation of email attachments that will be used for all files in CRM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are registered through the CRM webservice. For Dynamics CRM the maximum length for HTTP requests is ruled by the httpRuntime setting in the web.config:

```
<location path="MSCRMServices">
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="8192" />
```

By default the maximum size is 8 MB. This setting is limiting the size of your plugin assembly. In CRM Online you have no access to the web.config, so you cannot modify this limit.

Often plugin assemblies are 'blown up' by generated code, i.e. early bound types generated by the crmsvcutil tool. Consider using a more sophisticated tool, e.g. the CRM Early Bound Generator, which can be found on [CodePlex](https://xrmearlyboundgenerator.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Currently this size is determined by the 'SandboxClientMaxAssemblySizeInKByte' deployment property. According to the [Optimize assembly development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/guidance/server/optimize-assembly-development#consolidate-plug-ins-or-custom-workflow-activities-into-a-single-assembly) page the maximum DLL file size online is around 16MB and on-premise it's 8MB.

On-premise this could be increased to, for example to 16MB, by updating the MSCRM_CONFIG database, like so:

```
UPDATE [MSCRM_CONFIG].[dbo].[DeploymentProperties]
SET [IntColumn] = 16384
WHERE [ColumnName] = 'SandboxClientMaxAssemblySizeInKByte'
```

Source: [This post on the CRM forum](https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6cce8bec-9c1c-44be-b8e4-6ec754aa191e/crm-2013-isolated-plugin-size?forum=crmdevelopment)